# Error: return keyword must not be followed by an object expression in c# async code

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I have a following async code in C#:

```
public async Task GetPhotos(List<int> photoIds)
{
    List<Photos> photos = new List<Photos>();

    if (photoIds != null)
    {
        foreach (int photoId in photoIds)
        {
           Photo photo = await ImageRepository.GetAsync(photoId);

           if (photo != null)
              photos.Add(photo);
        }
    }

    return photos;        
}
```

On the return statement i am getting the following error message:

> Since GetPhotos(List photoIds) is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task'?

How to solve this error ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change your return type like this `Task<List<photos>>`

```
 public async Task<List<photos>> GetList()
    {

        List<Photos> photos = new List<Photos>();

        if (photoIds != null)
        {
            foreach (int photoId in photoIds)
            {
               Photo photo = await ImageRepository.GetAsync(photoId);

               if (photo != null)
                  photos.Add(photo);
            }
        }

        return photos;        
}
```

To call

```
var list = await GetList()
```

Answer (score 7):

An async method returns a `Task<T1,T2,T3...>` that shows whether it it complete and allows the caller to use `.Result` or `async` to retrieve the return value.

If there is no return value, an async method returns a `Task`. That it, it returns nothing when it completes.

Your method is defined as returning a `Task`, which means it returns nothing on completion, yet at the end of your method you return a `List<Photo>`. Therefore, the correct return type would be a `Task<List<Photo>>`.

You may wish to read [this post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Also, you have a typo in your sample code: `List<Photos>` -> `List<Photo>`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the return type of the method `Task<List<Photos>>` instead of `Task`.  When you call `GetPhotos`, use

```
var photos = await GetPhotos
```

photos will be of type `List<Photos>`. (The `await` keyword essentially extracts the `List<Photos>` object from the `Task`.)